# How do I implement Customized User Membership Provider

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm developing MVC 4 web application with C# in need of user privileges and roles. Currently, I created tables like this.

'privileges_table

```
     PrivilegeID | PrivilegeName
          1      |  Create
          2      |  Update
          3      |  Delete
          4      |  View
```

Roles_Table

```
     RolesID     | RolesName  | PrivilegeID  | RolesGroup
        1           Admin          1         |   1
        2           Admin          2         |   1
        3           Admin          3         |   1
        4           Secretary      2         |   4
        5           Remote User    4         |   5
```

User_Table

```
     UserID   |  UserName   | UserPass  | RoleGroup
       1      |  Wale       | m%^#@     |     1
       2      |  Jane       | k*&%$#    |     5
```

How do I implement the User Memebership Provider with the tables above? I've read through some materials online without help.

Comment: This is too broad of a question, I can't just rewrite MS's comprehensive sample, ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.100).aspx  What specific question do you need help on?

Answer (score 0):

MVC Membership logic already comes implemented with Internet Application project model.
You can either use that or create your own tables in database and representative model classes at mvc. 
What you're using its called a RBAC system (role based access control).

You should read more about RBAC, Membership and MVC filters (Action and authorization filters). Follow some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Dont. Your membership provider will be more buggy and less secure that the standard microsoft membership provider which is attacked million of time an hour without being broken. Its very easy to extend once you understand it and ultimately much less work. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx.

Comment: I found my way around it. Thanks guys.